# Are there more informative names?

Tags: logic, philosophy

Consider this statement: "There is only one smallest prime number greater than 1000." This statement is obviously true. We can denote this number with the letter n. Then we can look up on the Internet what this number is. This is 1009 because the previous number is 997.
There are two questions here:

1. Do we get new information when we find out that this number is 1009?
2. If we receive new information, then it turns out that there are more and less informative names of objects?

**EDIT:**

Clarifying the second question.In the example above, n and 1009 denote the same mathematical object, but the notation 1009 seems to me to give much more knowledge about the object than n.So the question is, does notation 1009 really provide more knowledge than n? For example, i can calculate the remainder of 1009 divided by 9 and get 1,but i think that cannot be done with notation n.

Comment: We start from a description and then we prove that there is an object that correspind to the description i.e. an object that is the referente of the description.

Comment: With the second step we have more knowledge: there are empty descriptions like "round square".

Comment: Question 1 is basically, “if information/data is true but isn’t useful, then is it really information?” This reminds me of, “if a tree falls in the woods…”. I don’t understand your second question due to the wording not making sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: You have discovered the distinction, first articulated by Gottlob Frege, between two kinds of meanings, “sense” and “reference”.  The expressions “2+2” and “4” have the same reference because they both denote the same mathematical object.  But they have different sense because they describe two different ways of identifying that object.

Comment: It's not one-sided: "the smallest prime > 1000" clearly denotes a prime number (we know that there are infinitely many primes and that therefore there is such a number), whereas we can't tell just from the numeral 1009 that it is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation you choose does not influence the amount of information you have, but may convey that information more usefully. The sentence

> The smallest prime greater than 1000 leaves a remainder of 1 when
> divided by 9.

says what you want to say, with no notation. To convince your reader that it's true you might have to show that the number is 1009. That argument might require some notation.